# Use one adapter for two ListViews is it good practice..?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-adapter

I have a list that I want to display differently in two fragments. 
That means I need two ListViews (one in each fragment) but do I also need two adapters ? Or can I simply use one adapter for the two list given that when the data changes, I want the two lists to update.

EDIT : Display differently means I want to display the tasks sorted by alphabetical order in the first fragment and on a calendar in the second fragment.

(Or maybe there is a simpler way to go about the problem ?)

The adapter :

```
public class TasksAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {

    public TasksAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Task> tasks) {
        super(context, 0, tasks);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        Task task = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_task, parent, false);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: try it. it doesn't sound as a good practice, but you can even try

Comment: can you explain a bit more what you mean by "display differently"?

Comment: keep in mind that you could simply create 2 instances of the same adapter class without thinking about this problem

Comment: and also add your current adapter code to your question

Comment: It it probably the simplest way to go about this but it sounds like duplication and means I have to update the two adapters each time the list changes.

Comment: I've used one adapter multiple times on occasions. However not with different display. However I have some that are cater for a ListView and a Spinner (i.e. they have both getView and getDropDownView methods).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly use a single adapter if the adapter is built in such a way that it accommodates the type of data you want to use in both `Fragment`'s.

This is dependent on the specifics of what you want to accomplish, but here are some things to consider:

- Simply instantiate two separate instances of the adapter and pass the instance into the `.setAdapter` method of your `ListView` or `RecyclerView`.
- You can programmatically use different view holders in your adapter, look into the `getItemViewType()` method.
- If the data in your adapter is more than simple primitives, consider writing a model class to model list objects that works with both types of data you are using.

Please note, you should probably be using a `RecyclerView`.